# Nginx failover with upstream load balancer not working, 504 when server 1 is down

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, docker, failover

I have an nginx docker container `balancer` that acts as a balancer for 3 nginx docker containers `server_1`, `server_2`, `server_3`.

Load balancing works fine, it hits all servers in a fashion depending on the specified method. However when I stop the first server using `docker stop server_1`, I get a `504`, even though the other servers are still up.

My balancer default file looks like this:

```
# don't redirect proxy
proxy_redirect  off;

upstream app {
    least_conn;
    server webserver_1;
    server webserver_2;
    server webserver_3;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_504;
        # proxy_set_header Host localhost;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I tried adding `fail_timeout=10s max_fails=1` to the three servers in the `upstream` directive, but no luck. I also tried adding the `proxy_next_upstream_tries 2;` directive, but this did not help either.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

What type of docker networking are you using? I wonder why the requests time-out. Any firewall rules?

For load balancing its generally bad to 'rely' on timeouts. Its better when the host (container) gets unavailable (smth. like 'no route to host') or the connection gets resettet (container available, but service not running).

Comment: Just a "bridge" network.

Comment: Try this: Run a backend container with `docker run --rm -ti --name backend nginx` and a frontend container with `docker run --rm -ti --name frontend --link backend ubuntu:trusty`. Install `curl` in the frontend container (`apt-get update && apt-get install curl`) and request a HTTP header from the backend (`curl -I backend`). Now abort the execution of the backend container. After some seconds try to request the header again. Now u should get a `curl: (7) Failed to connect to backend port 80: No route to host`.

Comment: The behaviour is strange indeed when using the bridge driver. I never noticed this. It needs some seconds before the container gets 'unavailable'. This should be faster IMO.

Comment: Okay, so did I actually do it right? Or do I need to adjust my default file? 

I was thinking of using docker-gen as a replacement.

Comment: What happens if you wait some minutes. Is NGINX still trying to use the first server?

Answer (score 0):

What I experienced is that it just uses all 3 servers as per the load balancing method, but does not mark the server as down.